# In java 8+ are only single argument method reference permitted in a stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Is it true to say that in a `Stream` in Java 8, you can only use method references that take a single argument (if you disallow wrapping the method reference with a method call)?

I assume so because in a stream at any time you are processing a single item.

Therefore:

- `Something::new` (must refer to a single arg constructor)
- `this::doSomething` (must take a single arg)
- `Something::doSomething`
  (must take a single arg)

...when used in a `Stream`. Is this rule always true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not. Some of the `Stream` methods take functional interfaces having a method with multiple arguments.

For example, `Stream`'s `sorted(Stream<T> Comparator<? super T> comparator)` method, takes a `Comparator`, whose method has two arguments.

Here's an example of using a method reference - `String::compareTo` - of a method having two arguments:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("a","d","c").sorted(String::compareTo).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

`Stream`'s `Optional<T> max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)` method is another similar example.

Comment: But in this case the method reference is wrapped in a method call (toMap). In my question, I was asking about any cases where it's not wrapped.

Comment: Excellent. I think the second part of your answer has answered my question.

Answer (score 5):

There are four types of methods references:

- A method reference to a static method i.e.

  `Class::staticMethod`  --> `(args) -> Class.staticMethod(args)`
- A method reference to an instance method of an object of a particular type. i.e.

  `ObjectType::instanceMethod` -->  `(obj, args) -> obj.instanceMethod(args)`
- A method reference to an instance method of an existing object i.e.

  `obj::instanceMethod` --> `(args) -> obj.instanceMethod(args)`
- A method reference to a constructor i.e.

  `ClassName::new` --> `(args) -> new ClassName(args)`

As you can see with the second example, a given method can take two arguments and still be translated to a method reference, this is true for the case of calling `sorted` , `min` , `max` etc.. of a stream.

credit to [Java 8 Method Reference: How to Use it](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx) for the examples above.

Comment: Just to add a point : `ObjectType::instanceMethod` can also be `obj -> obj.instanceMethod()` where the type of `obj` is `ObjectType`

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the [answer from Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53985938/1746118), you can possibly find a real life example better to understand.

Let's assume we have a method that adds an `Integer i` and an `intValue` of a `Long l` to return back as a `String s` representation. This would look like :

```
String convertToStringAfterAddingValues(Long l, Integer i) {
    return String.valueOf(l.intValue() + i);
}
```

In the world of `FunctionalInterface`, this could be represented as a `BiFunction` as an anonymous class:

```
BiFunction<Long, Integer, String> biFunctionAnonymous = new BiFunction<Long, Integer, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Long l, Integer i) {
        return String.valueOf(l.intValue() + i);
    }
};
```

which in the lambda world could then be represented as:

```
BiFunction<Long, Integer, String> biFunctLambda = (l, i) -> String.valueOf(l.intValue() + i);
```

the same can be represented using method reference with the object of the class the method resides in as :

```
BiFunction<Long, Integer, String> biFunctMethodReference = <YourClassInstance>::convertToStringAfterAddingValues;
```

Comment: This is useful but I don't think it addresses the question.

Comment: @AndyCribbens Its just an example of how more than one argument can be used within streams using method references. The exact answer to your question was anyway provided by Eran. Just to compare with your question `Something::doSomething (must take a single arg)` and the last line of code in the above example, you can see how it is not relying on a single argument instead two arguments at the same time.